# What is the easiest way to implement validation in asp.net Form build from view model?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, validation, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a model class, which I am using to create the form

```
Public Class Users
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property UserName As String
    Public Property UserNin As Int16
    Public Property UserType As String
    Public Property Password As String

    Property UserTypes As IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem) = {
            New SelectListItem With {.Value = "admin", .Text = "Admin"},
            New SelectListItem With {.Value = "doctor", .Text = "Doctor"},
            New SelectListItem With {.Value = "reception", .Text = "Receptionist"}
    }
End Class
```

My View class, using the above ViewModel to generate form utilising HTML Helpers

```
<% Using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "User", FormMethod.Post))%>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                User Name
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%= Html.TextBoxFor(Function(x) x.UserName)%>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                User NIN
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%= Html.TextBoxFor(Function(x) x.UserNin)%>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Password
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%= Html.PasswordFor(Function(x) x.Password)%>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%= Html.DropDownListFor(Function(x) x.UserType, Model.UserTypes)%>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Add New User" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<% End Using%>
```

Now what is the best way to add validation to this case?

---

Update:

Here is what I have tried in another case, but still I dont see any validation, the action is called and processes.

Here is my model class

```
Public Class LoginUser
    <Required()>
    Public Property UserName As String

    <Required()>
    <StringLength(8)>
    Public Property Password As String

End Class
```

This is the partial View

```
<% Using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "User", FormMethod.Post))%>
<% Html.EnableClientValidation()%>
<table ID="loginTable" runat="server">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="username">UserName</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= Html.TextBoxFor(Function(x) x.UserName)%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(x) x.UserName) %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= Html.TextBoxFor(Function(x) x.Password)%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(x) x.Password)%>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<% End Using%>
```

Login Action

```
<HttpPost()>
Function Login() As ActionResult
    If ModelState.IsValid Then
        Dim sql As String
        Dim username As String = Request.Form("username").ToString
        Dim password As String = Request.Form("password").ToString
        Dim dbHelper As New DBHelper(False)

        sql = "SELECT * FROM " & _tblName & " WHERE username = '" & username & "' and password = '" & password & "'"
        Try
            Dim dr As DataRow = dbHelper.ExecuteAndGetRow(sql)

            If Convert.ToInt16(dr.Item(0).ToString) > 0 Then
                Dim nin As String = dr.Item(4)
                Session("loggedin") = 1
                Session("logged") = dr.Item(0)
                Session("logged_nin") = dr.Item(4)
                ViewData("message") = "Login Successful"
                ViewData("show_loginForm") = False
            Else
                ViewData("message") = "Login failed"
                ViewData("show_loginForm") = True
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            ViewData("message") = "Login failed"
            ViewData("show_loginForm") = True
        End Try


        Return View()
    Else
        Return View()
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use data annotations. For example if the `UserName` field was required you decorate it with the `<Required>` attribute:

```
<Required>
Public Property UserName As String
```

and inside the view you put a corresponding placeholder for the error message:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(Function(x) x.UserName) %>
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(x) x.UserName) %>
```

or if you wanted to centralize all error messages in a single place you could use the ValidationSummary helper:

```
<%= Html.ValidationSummary() %>
```

And inside the POST controller action you could verify if the model is valid using `ModelState.IsValid` boolean property:

```
<HttpPost()>
Function Create(model As Users) As ActionResult
    If ModelState.IsValid Then
        ' validation succeeded => do some processing and redirect
        Return RedirectToAction("Create")
    End If

    ' validation failed => redisplay the same view so that the user
    ' can fix the errors
    Return View(model)
End Function
```

And here's an [article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256141%28VS.98%29.aspx) which explains this as well.

Comment: What does this `ModelState` mean?

Comment: It's a property of the controller. It contains all the values that are sent in the POST request when you submitted the form. For each value it contains a list of errors according to the data annotations you used in the model. If some of them failed, the `IsValid` will be set to false. So as shown in my answer you could check this property to know whether validation failed or succeeded.

Comment: Nice. Thank you so much Darin, I am learning so much from you.

Comment: Which action is called? Do you have an `<HttpPost>` controller action taking the model as parameter and returning the same view?

Comment: Yes, I do have them, but not exactly the same view, It posts to a different controller, and login part is a partial view and the `login` action has a view of its own to show the form again. But, client side validation is not coming. I followed as instructed in the reference you linked.

Comment: I have uploaded the Action Code, I was trying to mention the HTML Helper. :) Please see the forms.

Comment: Your `Login` action doesn't take the model as parameter. Look at my answer once again more carefully. You are manually reading the parameters from the request: `Dim username As String = Request.Form("username").ToString` which is absolutely useless whereas you could directly have your action take the model as parameter and it will be the default model binder that will automatically do the binding.

Comment: I missed. But I am not getting the client side validation and the message. What might be reason behind this?

Comment: You probably forgot to include the Microsoft*.js scripts which are used in MVC 2 for client side validation.

Comment: Sorry, it's not me that posted this comment. It is the automated system. I suggest you stop commenting here because otherwise this question might get locked by a moderator. You should consider starting a new question.

Comment: Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102433/no-validation-error-message-or-summary-while-using-dataannotation-validations) question. I have posted another question, focusing on the topic.