# Not getting validation Error Messages from DataAnnotation Validations

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, validation, data-annotations, html-helper

I am have a simple model class for Login, with few DataAnnotation Validations

```
Public Class LoginUser
    <Required()> _
    Public Property UserName As String

    <Required()> _
    <StringLength(8)> _
    Public Property Password As String

End Class
```

View is a **partial View** and is as follows:

```
<% Using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "User", FormMethod.Post))%>
<% Html.EnableClientValidation()%>

<%= Html.ValidationSummary() %>
<table ID="loginTable" runat="server">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= Html.LabelFor(Function(x) x.UserName)%>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= Html.TextBoxFor(Function(x) x.UserName)%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(x) x.UserName) %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= Html.LabelFor(Function(x) x.Password)%>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= Html.TextBoxFor(Function(x) x.Password)%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(x) x.Password)%>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<% End Using%>
```

I believe I have done all the things needed for validation message to show up, but it does not, neither does **clientside validation**. I have also included the following scripts, on the head region of Master Page

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

What is causing this problem? And what is the solution?

Comment: Show your controller. EDIT: I should say, your GET and POST action methods for Login.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add some error messages to your annotation

```
Public Class LoginUser
    <Required()(ErrorMessage:="Username is required.")> _
    Public Property UserName As String

    <Required(ErrorMessage:="Pssword is required.")> _
    <StringLength(8)> _
    Public Property Password As String

End Class
```

not sure if it will make a difference but try adding true like this

```
    <%= Html.ValidationSummary(true)%>
<% Html.EnableClientValidation(true)%>
```

Comment: @mrN see another suggestion above

Comment: So you know, adding `ValidationSummary` and `EnableClientValidation` goes into web.config. (not sure if it will do the trick, but you have to try it)

Comment: That didn't work. And I dont know where to put name in web.config

Comment: So it didn't work or you don't know where to put it? It cannot be both, man. Also, I hope you know how to use google? insert into google search box "ASP NET MVC Web.Config ValidationSummary EnableClientValidation" and see what you get back. Should lead in the right direction.